# Integrating Keycloak Spring Security Adapter in non Spring Boot application - Too many redirects issue

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to integrate **keycloak spring security adapter** in **non spring boot application**. I am getting **too many redirects**.

Request flow from browsers network log is as follows:

1. http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/user-reviews?sessionid=08b7488b38406fb5163e01b9832c2938&page=1&pageSize=5&tags=looks
2. http://localhost:8080/sso/login
3. http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/springdemo/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=product-app&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=f91bfb8a-c094-45d8-9ce9-e04c7bb07588&login=true&scope=openid
4. http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/springdemo/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=fM8Bg1gfB4F6inTA2ktzEFmGBeRpVwfDiJpfJdRyn8s&execution=94ba3135-45a8-4cb0-8679-4071581b3a20&client_id=product-app&tab_id=HVJ56HIW15A
5. http://localhost:8080/sso/login?state=f91bfb8a-c094-45d8-9ce9-e04c7bb07588&session_state=123021b6-56fd-4625-9ca5-dd6c66bf6347&code=911179d9-1c20-4431-9063-c72dba6ad68a.123021b6-56fd-4625-9ca5-dd6c66bf6347.5bd696d5-a141-481f-8af7-d8babfc24f47
6. http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/user-reviews?sessionid=08b7488b38406fb5163e01b9832c2938&page=1&pageSize=5&tags=looks
7. http://localhost:8080/sso/login
8. http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/springdemo/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=product-app&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=88228c02-20ac-4771-be41-37db20f9dcd6&login=true&scope=openid
9. http://localhost:8080/sso/login?state=88228c02-20ac-4771-be41-37db20f9dcd6&session_state=123021b6-56fd-4625-9ca5-dd6c66bf6347&code=9bb45414-2faa-40d4-898e-a0bbc28a66cf.123021b6-56fd-4625-9ca5-dd6c66bf6347.5bd696d5-a141-481f-8af7-d8babfc24f47
10. http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/user-reviews?sessionid=08b7488b38406fb5163e01b9832c2938&page=1&pageSize=5&tags=looks

**Steps 7, 8, 9, 10 are repeated until browser complaints of - Too many redirects**.

Following is my **security configuration**:

```java
package me.nageshkumar.auth.configuration;

import org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment;
import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder;
import org.keycloak.adapters.spi.HttpFacade.Request;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakSecurityComponents;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/user-reviews*").hasRole("user").anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AdapterDeploymentContext adapterDeploymentContext() throws Exception {
        AdapterConfig cfg = new AdapterConfig();
        cfg.setRealm("springdemo");
        cfg.setAuthServerUrl("http://localhost:8180/auth");
        cfg.setSslRequired("external");
        cfg.setResource("product-app");
        cfg.setPublicClient(true);
        cfg.setConfidentialPort(0);
        cfg.setPrincipalAttribute("preferred_username");
        KeycloakDeployment dep = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(cfg);
        AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean factoryBean = new AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean(
                new KeycloakConfigResolver() {
                    @Override
                    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(Request facade) {
                        return dep;
                    }
                });
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

}
```

Above configuration works in Spring Boot application without any issue.

**EDIT:**

Configuration also works in newly created non Spring Boot application.

But I have to integrate **Keycloak Spring Security Adapter** in an existing non Spring Boot application, where I am getting - **Too many redirects**.

I am using **6.0.1 version** of **Keycloak Spring Security Adapter**.

Any idea about possible scenario which could cause - Too many redirects issue.

Comment: Do you have any log for your application or keycloak ?